# setting readonly column by filtering by the TD object class

Tags: javascript, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I'm using the latest version 1.10.0 of [Datatables Plugin for JQuery](http://datatables.net/) and need to have some columns editable and some not. Since datatables does not offer this functionality out of the box and following directions from [here](http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/4887/making-column-read-only-disabled) I added in my `columns` initialization/specification a class `readonly` that I use to check against e.g.

```
"drawCallback": function(settings) {
  var dt = this;
  $('tbody td[class != "readonly"]').editable("/@context/edit/do",
```

This works but it is insufficient for my needs because I need to filter when `readonly` occurs as a substring of the class i.e. there are other classes as well e.g. `readonly sorting_1`. I have tried doing the following but it fails:

```
"drawCallback": function(settings) {
  var dt = this;
  $('tbody td[class.indexOf("readonly") == -1]').editable("/@context/edit/do",
```

with error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: tbody td[class.indexOf("readonly") == -1]
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use JavaScript expressions in selectors. What you want is probably jQuery's [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method, which allows you to pass it a function which returns `true` if an item in the set of matched elements should be kept.

Using this, your code can be re-written like this:

```
$('tbody td').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).hasClass('readonly')
}).editable("/@context/edit/do",
```

In the filtering function, I check if the `<td>` has the class `readonly`, and by reversing this check (using `!`), the function will return `false` whenever it has that class, resulting in the removal of the "read-only" `<td>` element(s) from the list that gets passed to the `editable` method.